# Why can't I dereference pointer to objects?

Tags: objective-c, object, pointers, dereference

Why can't I dereference pointers to objects or why aren't pointers to objects dereferenced?

```
myClass * object = [[myClass alloc]init];
[*object instanceMethod]; //Like this
[object instanceMethod]; //Instead of this
```

cause sending messages needs classes/objects as their receiver.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Objective-C syntax `[x foo]` is equivalent to C's `x->foo()`, and `x` is a pointer. Objective-C variables are always pointers; and objects are never variables -- they can *only* be managed through a pointer.

Comment: Is 'self' used instead of 'x' like 'self->foo()'?, although there is no 'self' in c.

Comment: @MiguelC: well, Objective-C is is an *extension* of C... there are bound to be new things in it. `self` is a pointer to the current object.

Comment: I would not say *equivalent* to C's `x->foo()` here, because `[x foo]` is translated by the compiler to `objc_msgSend(x, @selector(foo))`, and the method is resolved at runtime ...

Comment: @MartinR: Yeah, good point. It's *syntactically* equivalent, but behaves more like in C++.

Comment: @MartinR: What about sending messages to classes. I know that classes are also objects, but how is it translated by the compiler if it isn't a pointer?

Comment: @MiguelC: `Class` is declared as `typedef struct objc_class *Class`, so that is a pointer as well.